# Split array objects into array groups in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I have an array like below:

```
let totalArr = ["First","Second","Third","Fourth","First","Second", "Second"]
```

My Required output is:

```
let grouper = [["First","First"],["Second", "Second", "Second"],["Third"],  ["Fourth"]]
```

can anybody give optimal iterations?

Comment: You're asking an open-ended algorithm question - this might not do so well on SO. SO is meant for "I tried this. It's broken. I also tried this. What am I doing wrong?" type of questions.

Comment: I guess he wants something like grouping not sure if duplicate answer is same.

Comment: @TheTiger: Already reopened – I had misread the question, sorry about that!

Comment: @MartinR Oh my page was not refreshed. :) And I had the answer which now already has given by **Abdelahad**.

Comment: @TheTiger consider it your answer upvote it and get sportman badge

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish SO will banned my account ;). Its not fair.

Comment: :) no problem I was just joking.

Comment: Done for all the correct answers.

Answer (score 6):

```
 let totalArr = ["First","Second","Third","Fourth","First","Second", "Second"]

 let grouper =   (Dictionary(grouping: totalArr, by: { $0})).map {  $0.value}

 print(grouper)
```

**or**

```
  let arranged =   (Dictionary(grouping: totalArr, by: { $0})).values
 print(arranged)
```

Answer (score 3):

try this :)

You can pass any String array to the function and it will return your desired result:

```
func groupArr(totalArr: [String]) -> [Any]{
    var grouperArr = [[String]]()
    for i in totalArr{
        let arr = totalArr.filter({($0 == i)}) as [String]
        if(grouperArr.contains(arr) == false){
            grouperArr.append(arr)
        }
    }
    return grouperArr
}
```

Comment: Why return type is `[Any]` instead of `[[String]]` or `Array<Array<String>>` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Dictionay's grouping function to make a group and then get all values.

```
let totalArr = ["First","Second","Third","Fourth","First","Second", "Second"]

let group = Dictionary(grouping: totalArr) { (object) -> String in
    let lowerBound = String.Index(encodedOffset: 0)
    let upperBound = String.Index(encodedOffset: 1)
    return String(object[lowerBound...upperBound])
}
print("group :\(group.values)")
```